# How to show a progress dialog while waiting for share intent to pop up

Tags: android

I noticed on older devices that once you do a standard share intent (fb, twitter, email, etc) there is a few second delay until the actual share dialog is popped up.  I was wondering how you would be able to have a progress dialog pop up while you are waiting for this share dialog to show up?

Here is my code:

```
 private void share(String subject,String body) {
        Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        share.setType("text/plain");
        share.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, title);
        share.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share via"));
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

I figured out how to do it.  When you call startActivity(shareIntent) the onPause in your method gets called.  So to solve this I did the following:

- Create a class progress dialog variable.
- Show the progress dialog at the start of my share function.
- In the onPause i did the following:

---

```
if(dialog.isShowing()){
  dialog.dismiss();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't seem to be possible - you don't have any way of knowing when the Intent Chooser is ready to display. As far as your app is concerned, this appears to be an asynchronous operation.

To confirm this, you could try timing the function:

```
private void share(String subject,String body) {
    //Timing code
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    share.setType("text/plain");
    share.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, title);
    share.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share via"));

    //Timing code
    long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Log.d("Test", "Time for share function: " + (endTime-startTime) + "ms");
}
```

If you get a very small result, it means your function is executing quickly, and the bottleneck is in the Android system itself (which you can't affect).

If, on the other hand, you get something in the order of 500+ milliseconds, it could be worth using the method described by XepterX and [display a Progress Dialog](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#ProgressDialog).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest below method:

1. First create a progress dialog and show it
2. Call Share Activity
3. Hide progress dialog returning back to main activity (onResume)

Here is the code:

```
ProgressDialog shareWaitDialog;

private void shareIt() {
    String subject="Subject";
    String text  = "text....";
    shareWaitDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    shareWaitDialog.setTitle("Sharing...");
    shareWaitDialog.setMessage(subject);
    shareWaitDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    shareWaitDialog.show();

    Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
    sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,
            subject);
    sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
            text));
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent,
            "Share using:"));
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    if (shareWaitDialog != null && shareWaitDialog.isShowing())
        shareWaitDialog.hide();

    super.onResume();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems very difficult to show dialog, instead You Can Show Toast like "Waiting for Apps..." on Share Button Click. The Toast can fill the time gap.

```
mShare.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            Toast.makeText(ReferralActivity.this, "Waiting for Apps to Send", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            try {
                String sAux = "Content To Share";
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                i.setType("text/plain");
                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Sample");
                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,sAux);
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Share using:"));
            } catch(Exception e) {
                //e.toString();
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can try this code:

```
void share(String link) {
    final ProgressDialog ringProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", getString(R.string.please_wait), true);
    ringProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
            // your share method for sharing link or image or anything
                shareTextUrl(link);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            ringProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }).start();
    ringProgressDialog.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use an AsyncTask() to help you show a dialog progress, for example,

```
 private class TestTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    protected void onPreExecute() { 
        //show dialog 
    }

    protected void doInBackground(Object... params) { 
        private void share(subject,body); 
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
        //cancel dialog
    }
}
```

and start the task by

```
new TestTask().execute();
```

You can find more info regarding AsyncTask() from [the documentation here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Comment: I did not downvote your response, but I would upvote it if you added more specific code. These methods alone won't help an Android n00b figure out what an AsyncTask is. Adding a link to the android documentation, and actually showing how to execute the asynctask, and to open and close the dialog would be a great improvement.

Comment: can't understand either the downvote and looking for a solution. This could be on, but not this I want to implement. Upvoting to fix somebody else oppinion